# Xcode cannot find installed library

Tags: c, xcode

I am using Mac OS X 10.8 with Xcode. I have installed the `jansson` library, with the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
```

Everything went fine and the library installed correctly. I have created a smple *.c* file with a text editor and tried to include the `<jansson.h>` file. I builded everything and it gave no errors, meaning that the library is installed on my system.

Now, Xcode doesn't find the library at all, saying that `<jansson.h>` is not found. I have tried to restart my Mac, but nothing happens. If anyone knows a possible solution, I will be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Did it get deleted since then maybe? or moved out of your normal path? Did you do a search to verify the headerfile is still present as you expect?

Comment: Does xcode has proper library path? for this library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue, by going under *Build phases*, and searching for `HEADER_SEARCH_PATH`. Then I changed the search path label with `/usr/local/include`, where the library was installed.